# How do I access webhook data for a sigle user in a Sveltekit project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, webhooks, sveltekit

I am currently working on a sveltekit project about connecting with APIs. Once a session is created, you choose your API provider you want to connect to. The prompt to choose a provider is a button that redirects to a seperate site. I currently have this outside site send me a webhook to /webhook/+server.js. The thing I can't figure is how I can make this lead to updating the client side for the correct user withought requiring action on the user's end. Currently, all the data about the sessions is stored in cookies that I access and mainipulate from /+page.server.js.

I've looked through the sveltekit docs along with numerous other tutorials and I haven't found something that relates to my exact issue. I spent time going down the rabbit hole of regular hooks with sveltekit but that seemed to lead me to a dead end.